# Script to create symlinks for dotfiles in a Git repository

Tags: beginner, bash, error-handling, file-system

I have a GitHub repository containing all my dotfiles for `bash`, `tmux` and `neovim`. I'm using a Mac and whenever I factory reset it I like to just pull repository from GitHub and link all the dotfiles to the one in the repo.

Now I wrote a script to automatically create these symlinks and handle possible errors on the way.

This is what I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

RED=`tput setaf 1`
GREEN=`tput setaf 2`
RESET=`tput sgr0`

custom_link() {
  file_loc="$1"
  symlink_loc="$2"

  # Check whether original file is valid
  if [[ ! -e "$file_loc" ]]; then
    echo "${RED}WARNING${RESET}: Failed to link $symlink_loc to $file_loc"
    echo "         $file_loc does not exist"
    return 1
  fi

  # Check whether symlink already exists
  if [[ -e "$symlink_loc" ]]; then
    if [[ -L "$symlink_loc" ]]; then
      if [[ "$(readlink $symlink_loc)" == "$file_loc" ]]; then echo "--> $symlink_loc -> $file_loc ${GREEN}exists${RESET}."; return 0; fi

      current_dest=$(readlink "$symlink_loc")
      echo "It seems like $symlink_loc already is symlink to $current_dest."
      read -p "Do you want to replace it? [Y/N] " -n 1 -r
      if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
      then
        echo
        echo "Removing current symlink..."
        unlink  $symlink_loc
        ln -s "$file_loc" "$symlink_loc"
        echo "Created a symlink $symlink_loc -> $file_loc"
        return 0
      fi
      echo
      return 2
    else
      echo "It seems like $symlink_loc already exists."
      read -p "Do you want to [d]elete, [m]ove (-> $HOME/.other/) or [k]eep $symlink_loc? " -n 1 -r
      if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Dd]$ ]]
      then
        printf "\nDeleting $symlink_loc..."
        rm -rf "$symlink_loc"
        ln -s "$file_loc" "$symlink_loc"
        echo "Created a symlink $symlink_loc -> $file_loc"
        return 0
      elif [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Mm]$ ]]; then
        printf "\nMoving $symlink_loc to ~$HOME/.other..."
        mkdir "$HOME/.other"
        mv "$symlink_loc" "$HOME/.other"
        ln -s "$file_loc" "$symlink_loc"
        echo "Created a symlink $symlink_loc -> $file_loc"
        return 0
      else
        printf "\nKeeping $symlink_loc...\n"
        return 2
      fi
    fi
  fi

  symlink_dir=$(dirname "$symlink_loc")
  if ! mkdir -p "$symlink_dir" ; then
   echo "${RED}WARNING${RESET}: Failed to link $symlink_loc to $file_loc"
   echo "         Could not create folder $symlink_dir/"
   return 1
  fi

  ln -s "$file_loc" "$symlink_loc"
  echo "Created a symlink $symlink_loc -> $file_loc"
  return 0
}

custom_link "$HOME/.dotfiles/bash/.bashrc" "$HOME/.bash_profile"
custom_link "$HOME/.dotfiles/bash/.bashrc" "$HOME/.bashrc"
custom_link "$HOME/.dotfiles/nvim/init.vim" "$HOME/.config/nvim/init.vim"
custom_link "$HOME/.dotfiles/tmux/.tmux.conf" "$HOME/.tmux.conf"
```

It was my very first time writing a bash script and I just googled, whenever I had a specific question.

I choose the return codes as follows: 
- `0` for successful creation
- `1` for failure
- `2` for cases, when the link was not created, because the user decided so.

My questions are:

- How is my general bash programming style? Any important idioms I missed?
- The script contains a lot of duplicate code (especially the three lines: `ln -s "$file_loc" "$symlink_loc"`, `echo "Created a symlink $symlink_loc -> $file_loc"` and `return 0`. How can I reduce the number of duplicates?
- How could I implement more successful return values?
- I handles a lot of cases (the file already exists, etc.). Did I miss any important cases?
- Currently the function `custom_link` displays a lot of text. How could I outsource this echoing to the outside of the function? The function should do the bare minimum (maybe connected to the question about useful return codes).

Comment: [Follow-up question](/q/181950/9357)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I noticed that some of your questions have similar aspects, so I clustered them to provide a single answer:

**"How is my general bash programming style?"**
**"How can I reduce the number of duplicates?"**
**"How could I outsource this echoing to the outside of the function?"**

Shell script is ugly compared to other scripting languages, so we need to make an *extra* effort to keep it readable.

So here are some suggestions to improve the readability of your script:

- Check your script with [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) for insights on best practices and idioms.
- Extract those file checks to functions with meaningful names, so that the reader won't need to remember (or lookup) what each flag means:

  ```
  if [[ -e "$symlink_loc" ]]; then
      if [[ -L "$symlink_loc" ]]; then
  ```

  could become:

  ```
  if file_exists "$symlink_loc"; then
      if is_symlink "$symlink_loc"; then
  ```
- Hide *low level details* that are polluting the `custom_link` function:

  ```
  custom_link() {
      # 1. checking if original file is valid
          # 1.1 if not valid, print error message and return 1

      # 2. handling existing file where symlink should be placed
          # 2.1 if is already existing symlink
              # 2.1.1 if symlink already points to file, print success and return 0
              # 2.1.2 otherwise, ask user if symlink should be replaced
                  # 2.1.2.1 if yes, replace it

          # 2.2 if is a regular file
              # 2.2.1 prompt user to delete, move or keep file
                  # 2.2.1.1 if delete, delete file and place symlink
                  # 2.2.1.2 if move, create dir $HOME/.other, move file there and place symlink
                  # 2.2.1.3 if keep, print "keeping the file"

      # 3. creating symlink
          # 3.1 extract dirname of symlink
          # 3.2 try to create extracted dir
              # 3.2.1 if fails, print error and return 1
          # 3.3 create symlink, print success and return 0
  }
  ```

  It should be easy for the reader of `custom_link` to understand what is going on, on a *high level*:

  ```
  custom_link() {
      file_loc="$1"
      symlink_loc="$2"

      if ! file_exists "$file_loc"
      then
          return invalid_file_error "$file_loc" "$symlink_loc"
      fi

      if file_exists "$symlink_loc"
      then
          return handle_existing_file "$file_loc" "$symlink_loc"
      fi

      create_new_symlink "$file_loc" "$symlink_loc"
  }
  ```

  And then you can hide *lower level details* of each step on their own dedicated functions. (You can apply this recursively, until the functions are very small and obvious)
  Here are some examples:

  ```
  file_exists() { test -e "$1"; }

  invalid_file_error() {
      file_loc="$1"
      symlink_loc="$2"

      echo "${RED}WARNING${RESET}: Failed to link $symlink_loc to $file_loc"
      echo "         $file_loc does not exist"
      return 1
  }

  handle_existing_file() {
      file_loc="$1"
      symlink_loc="$2"

      if is_symlink "$symlink_loc"
      then
          return handle_existing_symlink "$file_loc" "$symlink_loc"
      else
          return handle_existing_regular_file "$file_loc" "$symlink_loc"
      fi
  }
  ```

---

**"Any important idioms I missed?"**
**"How could I implement more successful return values?"**

The convention is to return `0` for success and anything else for errors.

So you got it right when you are returning `0` (symlink already there pointing to expected file) and `1` (file doesn't exist).

But when you prompt the user on which actions should be taken, you are *successfully* executing what was requested, but returning a `2`.

If you think from the user's perspective, the exit code should be `0`, since the script did exactly what the user wanted.

---

**"Did I miss any important cases?"**

The user can choose to move a file to `$HOME/.other`, but what should happen if there is already a file there (on `$HOME/.other`) with the same name, maybe from a previous run?

Comment: Thank you really much for your answer! I'll probably accept it in the next few hours.